# CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This code is causing the error:

```
- (NSString *)cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername:(NSString *)username
{
    NSString *cache = [NSString stringWithString:[settings objectForKey:@"twitterCache"]];
    if (cache.length > 0)
    {
        twitterLoginShown = YES;
        return cache;       
    }
    return @" ";
}
```

I can't even step through each line in this block of code for some reason. I'm not exactly sure what the error is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells that `[settings objectForKey:@"twitterCache"]` returns `nil`. Check if `settings` contains a value for the key `@"twitterCache"`.